# Joining uneven strings conditionally using list comprehension

Tags: python, string, join, list-comprehension

I am using the following code to join the 2 letter abbreviation, the first name and last name- so that every 3 words become a phrase. However there are cases where the name contains a "Jr" as in the string sample below, therefore breaking this otherwise working list comprehension.

```
span = 3
#string sample 
words = words = ['QB', 'Teddy', 'Bridgewater','RB', 'Dalvin', 'Cook', 'WR', 'Keenan', 'Allen', 'TE', 'Dalton', 'Schultz', 'WR', 'Odell', 'Beckham', 'Jr']
item= [" ".join(words[i:i+span]) for i in range(0, len(words), span)]
```

Is there a way to conditionally join to a span of 4 when "Jr." is the 4th word in this case?
What I currently get:

```
['QB Teddy Bridgewater', 'RB Dalvin Cook', 'WR Keenan Allen', 'TE Dalton Schultz', 'WR Odell Beckham', 'Jr']
```

But expected output should be:

```
['QB Teddy Bridgewater', 'RB Dalvin Cook', 'WR Keenan Allen', 'TE Dalton Schultz', 'WR Odell Beckham Jr']
```

Comment: You should organize the `words` list better, so you know where each name begins and ends.

Comment: Like nested lists `[['QB', 'Teddy', 'Bridgewater'],['RB', 'Dalvin', 'Cook'], ['WR', 'Keenan', 'Allen'], ['TE', 'Dalton', 'Schultz'], ['WR', 'Odell', 'Beckham', 'Jr']]`

Comment: Where does `words` comes ? Do you have any control on how it is built ?

Comment: The incoming string originally looks something like this, with special charactors, etc 
**("['QB Teddy Bridgewater', 'RB Dalvin Cook', 'RB Josh Jacobs', 'WR Marquise Brown', 'TE Mike Gesicki']", 'WR Odell Beckham Jr.')'**
  and I have been trying to strip and readd the special charactors, but perhaps I can salvage the name separators from this view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each group starts with an uppercase abbreviation, you can join all the strings together, prefixing the abbreviations with an end of line and others with a space.  Then split the resulting string on end of lines and drop the first (empty) entry.

```
words = ['QB', 'Teddy', 'Bridgewater','RB', 'Dalvin', 'Cook', 'WR', 'Keenan', 'Allen', 'TE', 'Dalton', 'Schultz', 'WR', 'Odell', 'Beckham', 'Jr']

items = "".join(" \n"[s[:2]==s.upper()]+s for s in words).split("\n")[1:]

print(items)
['QB Teddy Bridgewater', 'RB Dalvin Cook', 'WR Keenan Allen', 'TE Dalton Schultz', 'WR Odell Beckham Jr']
```

*If the list of abbreviations is known, it would be better to replace `[s[:2]==s.upper()]` with membership in a set: `[s in {'QB','RB','WR','TE'}]` (you should hold the set in a separate variable though)*

If you don't mind using a library, you can do the same thing more concisely using a regular expression for the substitution of spaces with end of lines:

```
items = re.sub(r" (?=[A-Z]{2} )","\n"," ".join(words)).split("\n")
```

*This may be somewhat unreliable given that any name containing a two letter uppercase word would cause an inappropriate split (e.g. `["RB","OJ", "Simpson"]`). With a known list of abbreviations, this can be avoided by placing them in the pattern:*

```
items = re.sub(r" (?=(QB|RB|WR|TE) )","\n"," ".join(words)).split("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your last solution is what I needed although will test it before accepting

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be using of regular expressions:

```py
import re

print(list(re.findall(r"([A-Z]{2}.+?)\s*(?=[A-Z]{2}|\Z)", " ".join(words))))
```

Prints:

```py
['QB Teddy Bridgewater', 'RB Dalvin Cook', 'WR Keenan Allen', 'TE Dalton Schultz', 'WR Odell Beckham Jr']
```